# cannot find name 'cordova'.(cordova is undefined)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

This is my first time using ionic + cordova to develop a hybrid app.
I need to get my version number in the app, which has the following code:

```
showVersion() {
  cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {
    alert(version);
  });}
```

When I run 'ionic cordova run android', I will get an error and tell me that 'cannot find cordova'.

I am using the android emulator.It's good working.

I also confirmed that I have `.

if i try to 'ionic cordova run browser', and i will get an same error.

so,What is the cause of this error? How should I solve it? ?

I hope to get your help.thanks so mauch!

Comment: i have <script src='cordova.js'></script>

Answer (score 1):

Please use the Native Plugin to get the AppVersion correctly:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/

Answer (score -1):

Add following statement after just your packages import statements.

Example :

```
//your packages import statements 
declare var cordova:any;
```